# Text to columns in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which stores data about products for sale.  One of the fields is called "bullets" and has a series of bullet points separated by a comma that give a description of the product.

For example:
*"Butterfly print, Frilled hem,Adjustable straps,V-neckline with ruched detail,Sleeveless,Made from a comfortable jersey fabric,Length from (approx): 99cm/38.9",100% cotton,Machine washable,"*

There is a unique product code for each line.  I need to split the bullet points out into multiple rows, so I can apply logic to them, any containing a % will be fabric composition, which is the data I need.  There can be multiple entries for fabric comp and i need them all.
Any idea how I can do this in SQL Server 2012?
Please note - i completely understand that the ideal scenario is to have the data stored better in the first place, but this is not in my control!

Many thanks

From this:

[image: before]

to this:

[image: after]

Comment: Might be of your interest .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991953/how-to-split-string-by-character-into-separate-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: Those aren't columns, those are rows....